# TextView ignoring EditText style on device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-styles

I have TextView where I apply the EditText style to it, as follows:

```
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="Click here"
            android:theme="@android:style/Widget.EditText"
            android:singleLine="true" android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:onClick="openDialog"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

In Design mode everything looks fine (API 22), but on the device (API16), the TextView doesn't have the style of the EditText.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

Using Api 19 or Api 16 in design mode, the TextView style is not the same as the EditText. So it's API-related.

Do I need an appcompat jar?

Comment: Can you show me screenshots?

Comment: android:theme is not recommended to use for styling a single view. You should be using android:style. Also the style android:style/Widget.EditText picks the devices default style. So actually the behavior you are seeing is totally expected.

Comment: @Rolfツ When I use android:style the app doesn't compile. If I use EditText style I would assume that the TextView is displayed correctly as I want it to look like an EditText.

Comment: Again, you are using a style which is meant to be different. So there is nothing wrong, this is expected behavior. You should create an API independent style first.

Comment: @Rolfツ How can I get the EditText style and use that one for a TextView?